# Crack animation on shadow catcher (2.80)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, shadowcatcher

I have an motion-tracked animation of a dart hitting the ground and sticking. It has shadow, materials, everything. But I want the effect of cracks forming when the dart hits the ground, but I can't do that with the shadow catcher (because it is invisible.) What is the best way to do this?

BTW, I have been researching and trying many things, so I am not expecting any responses for a while. :)

Comment: Given that you are a patient person, watch [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mg8jSotXmBI&feature=youtu.be). This was done in Cinema4D but the main principles can be used in blender. Track the footage. Create a plane and fracture it (maybe the fracture modifier can be helpful ), then displace the fragments. For compositing they are using the Ambient Occlusion pass. But to be more convincing you should really try to recreate the material of the floor so that you can have a different material show between the cracks. See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iN5vp--JFA

Comment: and: https://www.blendernation.com/2017/10/18/used-fracture-modifier-last-video/#prettyPhoto

Comment: @cegaton thanks! I'll try it. And the fracture modifier is coming in the final release of blender 2.8?

Comment: Could an alternative be to first render out my scene fully, then import it back as another motion tracking project, track it, and add the cracks separately?

Comment: Do the motion tracking first, so that you have a sense of how the camera moves and you can place the geometry that needs to be modified in a 3d space.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!